# Trying to find an efficient method to process all transactions directed to my BTC address

Tags: bitcoind, development

I am building a website which involves in the processing of transactions of BTC. My current and most efficient plan to complete this would be to call these bitcoin-cli commands and process the data accordingly: 
`getblockcount` - get block height 
`getblockhash blockheight-5` - get the block hash for the last 5 blocks 
`listsinceblock blockhash` - list all transactions since then

I would run this order of commands every 5-10 seconds. I would like to know if this method wont screw me over at all (skipping transactions, etc). I might just be too paranoid about clients not getting what they paid for and just want a guaranteed method that no transactions slip by. I was hoping to call a method that can list all transactions since a certain time but that wasn't available. Now to the question:

Is this method CPU/Network intensive?
Is it a safe method?
What are my alternatives?

Comment: If you are getting the last 5 blocks and logging all transactions since then, why would you run this every 5-10 seconds? 

I think you'd be safe running it every N minutes.

Are you storing this in a database?

Comment: It's possible, though unlikely, that more than 5 blocks could be mined in those 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Despite that probability, I'd rather not take that risk.

Comment: Please edit the title to summarize your question's topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found the answer to my own question**
To make sure every transaction goes through my script I have decided to use `walletnotify`. This is a feature of `bitcoind` and will run a bash script every time there is a new transaction with the transaction id. I was able to place this in my `.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` file with the parameters like so:
`walletnotify=/bin/echo %s | /bin/nc -U /root/nodejs.sock`
I used netcat to bridge my requests from bash to NodeJS however you can use your `%s` transaction data any way you like.